# como cambiar la codificación para firmar un documento en xml con utf-8 en c#

Tags: c#, xml, codificación

Me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación la cual se encarga de generar documentos xml y esta los firma con una firma simple Xades Enveloped,

El proceso que tengo para firmar es el siguiente:

1. Genero el archivo xml.
2. Cambio a utf-8 el archivo.
3. Este archivo lo firmo, se guarda como utf-8 with boom (o algo así)
4. convierto ese archivo firmado a utf-8

hasta el momento el código que uso para firmar los documentos es este

```
private static void FirmarDocumento(string pathXmlDocument, string pathCert, string passCert, string pathXmlSignet)
{

    XmlDocument documentXml = new XmlDocument();
    documentXml.Load(pathXmlDocument);

    SignedXml firmado = new SignedXml(documentXml);

    var cert = RSA_helper.GetX509Certificate(pathCert, passCert);
    firmado.SigningKey = (RSA)cert.PrivateKey;
    firmado.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1";

    //digest info
    Reference reference = new Reference();
    reference.Uri = "#Documento101";
    reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1";

    firmado.AddReference(reference);

    // with the public key will be added in the signature part. 
    KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
    keyInfo.AddClause(new RSAKeyValue((RSA)cert.PrivateKey));
    keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(cert));

    firmado.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
    firmado.ComputeSignature();

    XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = firmado.GetXml();

    // buscamos el ultimo elemento del documento para agregarle la firma
    XmlElement elemento = (XmlElement)documentXml.SelectSingleNode(@"//Document/Content/adu/TmstFirma[last()]");

    XmlNode parent = elemento.ParentNode;
    parent.InsertAfter(xmlDigitalSignature, elemento);
    documentXml.Save(pathXmlSignet);

}
```

Ya generado el archivo lo paso por una función que se encarga de dejarlo en UFT-8 (me lo están pidiendo así):

```
private static void ConvertirUTF8(String sourcePath)
{
    File.SetAttributes(sourcePath, FileAttributes.Normal);

    var sinUtf8Bom = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false);
    var contenido = File.ReadAllLines(sourcePath);

    File.SetAttributes(sourcePath, FileAttributes.Normal);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(sourcePath, contenido, sinUtf8Bom);
}
```

Si yo reviso la codificación me sale en UTF-8, pero si después quiero validar el archivo con su firma esta no la está pasando.

Yo creo es porque como ya generé el archivo después lo estoy manipulando al convertirlo a utf-8, y cuando quiero validar la firma me sale rechazado.

Qué me hace falta en mi función **FirmarDocumento** para que los archivos que firme salgan ya en UTF-8? así podría eliminar esta función para convertir. Estoy buscando pero por el momento no he encontrado nada.

Alguien sabe?

Muchas Gracias

Comment: La diferencia entre utf8 con BOM y sin él, es que si usas BOM se añaden 3 bytes adicionales al inicio del archivo, que sin el BOM no están. Si no entiendo mal, estás firmando un documento que tiene el BOM y en cambio intentando validar otro que no lo tiene. Si los archivos no son iguales la validación fallará necesariamente porque en la firma se hace un hash del archivo completo (incluyendo el BOM) que no coincidirá con el hash del archivo sin BOM.

Comment: ok... pero yo cuando genero el primer archivo que es soló el xml con los datos si se me genera con Boom, peor después lo convierto a utf-8, después con otra función le cargo la firma al documento. O esto igual afecta?

Comment: Si añades la firma al documento, alteras el documento. El proceso de validación deberá separar lo que es la firma del resto del documento (supongamos que lo hace). Lo que queda como "resto del documento" debe ser igual (a nivel de bytes) a lo que había cuando lo firmaste. Si al firmarlo tenía un BOM, pero el que validas no lo tiene, no son iguales y ya verificación fallará.

Comment: te digo los pasos que hago, genero el xml (viene con boom), después este archivo lo dejo en utf-8 y este archivo en utf-8 lo firmo. Cuando estoy firmando me lo volvía a dejar con Boom, pero le agregué un par de lineas a mi función y ahora me firma en utf-8, lo puedes ver más abajo, lo tengo como respuesta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Así a bote pronto se me ocurre que conviertas tu archivo a la codificación que quieras antes de firmarlo.

En general el proceso de firma de documentación en general sirve (entre otras cosas) para asegurarse de que el documento no ha sido alterado con posterioridad a la firma, y cambiarle la codificación es una alteración.

Por tanto yo probaría, cogiendo tu mismo código:

```
private static void FirmarDocumento(string pathXmlDocument, string pathCert, string passCert, string pathXmlSignet)
{

    XmlDocument documentXml = new XmlDocument();

    ConvertirUTF8(String sourcePath)  //Conviertelo antes

    documentXml.Load(pathXmlDocument);

    SignedXml firmado = new SignedXml(documentXml);


    ...
```

Yo he tenido ese mismo requerimiento por parte de un cliente y en el momento en que guardo el archivo la primera vez lo hago ya sin el BOM. El código que uso es:

```
    string rutaDelDoc = @"C:\temp\datos.xml";
    string XML = "contenido del XML, yo lo obtengo serializando un objeto";

    // y así lo guardo
    Encoding UTF8SinBOM = new UTF8Encoding(false);
    File.WriteAllText(rutaDelDoc, XML, UTF8SinBOM);
    ...
```

Adicionalmente en SO en inglés, proponen otra forma de hacerlo, con un `XmlTextWriter`, te `[enlazo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942825/xdocument-saving-xml-to-file-without-bom) a la pregunta y el código relevante de la respuesta es:

```
var doc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
    new XElement("root", new XAttribute("note", "boogers"))
);
using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(".\\ejemplo.xml", new UTF8Encoding(false)))
{
    doc.Save(writer);
}
```

Si además quieres indicar el encondig dentro del fichero XML 
Revisando la documentación de MS sobre `XmlDocument` [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.save?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_XmlDocument_Save_System_String_) veo que hay una propiedad `XmlDeclaration.Encoding`

> The XmlDeclaration of the current XmlDocument object determines the encoding attribute in the saved document. The value of the encoding attribute is taken from the XmlDeclaration.Encoding property. If the XmlDocument does not have an XmlDeclaration, or if the XmlDeclaration does not have an encoding attribute, the saved document will not have one either.

Básicamente lo que dice la documentación es que a la hora de generar el XML, generes también su declaración. De todos modos esto último solo te sirve para poner dentro del fichero XML el encoding, pero creo que no fuerza a que se grave en disco de una determinada manera (de hecho no podrías indicar que se use o no BOM).

Comment: voy a probar, porque lo había hecho, pero al final...... nop, igual me lo genera con encoding: utf-8 with BOM.

Comment: @SebastiánMiranda te amplio la respuesta... tal vez la solución esté en el punto en el que generas el fichero XML, suponiendo que lo generas tú.

Comment: Con tu respuesta y revisando otras cosas di con la solución, solo me queda una duda pero creo que es un poco rebuscado, el archivo va con CRLF *Windows Line Endings* y creo que los documentos los revisan en un sistema Linux, esto podría afectar?

Comment: @SebastiánMiranda no lo se, yo lo enviaria y a ver que te dicen. Cuando yo he tenido que quitar el BOM tambien era porque quien trataba el xml lo hacia desde Linux, pero de los saltos de línea nunca me dijeron nada. Yo además suelo serializar un objeto y de ahi saco el XML, con lo que solo tiene un CRLF al final del documento (el xml es como su fuera una sola linea).

Comment: ok, bueno yo igual serializo el xml, la diferencia con lo que me dices es que el mio viene indentado, pero como dices tú, voy a esperar a ver qué me dicen. Gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Esto es en respuesta a @Marc y para mi, ya que pude dar con una respuesta pero de igual forma algo me falta.

Pude "convertir" el archivo a utf-8, para ello utilicé las siguientes lineas:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);

XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ruta_completa, settings);
```

El código de la función para firmar es la siguiente:

```
private static void FirmarDocumento(string pathXmlDocument, string pathCert, string passCert, string pathXmlSignet,string ruta, string rut, string fecha, string tipo)
{

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();    
    doc.Load(pathXmlDocument);

    SignedXml firmado = new SignedXml(doc);

    var cert = RSA_helper.GetX509Certificate(pathCert, passCert);
    firmado.SigningKey = (RSA)cert.PrivateKey;
    firmado.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1";

    //digest info
    Reference reference = new Reference();
    reference.Uri = "#Documento101";
    reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1";

    firmado.AddReference(reference);

    // with the public key will be added in the signature part. 
    KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
    keyInfo.AddClause(new RSAKeyValue((RSA)cert.PrivateKey));
    keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(cert));

    firmado.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
    firmado.ComputeSignature();

    XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = firmado.GetXml();

    // inserto la firma donde la necesito
    XmlElement elemento = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode(@"//Document/Content/adu/TmstFirma[last()]");

    XmlNode parent = elemento.ParentNode;
    parent.InsertAfter(xmlDigitalSignature, elemento);

    //esta es la parte que agregué ********************************
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);


    string ruta_completa = ruta + rut + " - " + tipo + " - " + fecha + " - N - Firmado.xml";
    //esta linea igual es nueva ****************************
    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ruta_completa, settings);
    doc.Save(writer);
    writer.Close();

}
```

Firmo y guarda en utf-8, pero aún me dicen que no pasa la firma, estaba pensando que quizás tenga algo que ver con el orden en que voy firmando el archivo? Primero pasar el archivo a utf-8, después firmar?? Se puede hacer eso?